# how to randomly split file in three equal files, by row in bash?

Tags: awk

I have a line for randomly splitting it in half:

```
'BEGIN {srand()} {f = FILENAME (rand() <= 0.5 ? ".base" : ".target"); print > f}' file.txt
```

I need a method like this one, but to split file in three ~equal parts.
One messy solution would be to split in 0.3/0.7 with existing script and further the "0.7" part in .5/.5. But i would appreciate shorter solution.

Comment: Equal sizes would be fine. Optimally one would be able to set the ratio, e.g. 0.3, 0.3, 0.4 or 0.8, 0.1, 0.1.

Random and non-overlapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for approxmiately expected equal sizes (no guarantees, since based on underlying randomness)

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{srand()} {s=int(rand()*3)+1; print > (FILENAME"."s)}' file
```

for exact equality (within rounding), you can do

```
$ awk -v n=3 '{print > FILENAME"."(NR%n + 1)}' file
```

however, the file will be split without any random selection of rows.
If you want random selection and keep the relative order of the rows, the best solution I guess is using `shuf` and the above script combination

```
$ cat -n file | shuf > file.shuf
$ awk -v n=3 '{c=NR%n+1; print | "sort -n | cut -f2 > "FILENAME".c}' file.shuf &&  rm file.shuf
```

we add the line numbers to the original file so that the split files will have the same record order.